# Looking for a pure object oriented language

Tags: programming-languages, oop

I think object oriented programming is overrated, however I want to learn this paradigm. I have been trying to do this in PHP 5 and C++ with QT 4. Unfortunately, I tend to program in structured way, I do not use much of inheritance nor multiple instances. I think I have to learn a pure object oriented language that force me to use above features.

I think the best option is probably to learn Ruby. Could You confirm or name better alternative?

I work mainly on a x86-64 Linux.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I tend to program in structured way," -- How is Object Oriented programming not structured programming?

Comment: @Machine, Have you seen a "new to programming" programmer's Java code?

Comment: @Aiden Bell - Have you seen any 'new to programming' programmer's code? :)

Comment: Machine: Probably he means that he tends to program in a procedural way. In my experience object-oriented programming and procedural programming take two very different approaches to problem solving, and produce two very different kinds of code. (Procedural, incidentally, has its strengths and IMHO is underrated these days.)

Comment: you can write crappy code in any language, no language is going to force you to have the discipline to use OO principals and techniques any more than any other. I

Comment: @Michas I agree with those below. Find an excellent programmer and review each other's code, and if that person has _used_ smalltalk, then all the better. That and shop around for programming user groups.

Comment: Creating new classes of objects in C++ is too complicated. QT doesn't help. I can do this, however it is faster to program in somewhat style of pure C. This is the reason I need other language to learn.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Object-oriented programming isn't about syntax. It a programming paradigm.

A language can force you to use objects (if *everything* is an object, for example) but **using one of those languages isn't going to "force" you to learn object-oriented programming**.

> I do not use much of inheritance nor multiple instances

You have to learn when **and why** you use these techniques (data abstraction, encapsulation, polymorphism, and inheritance) to *think in objects*. Get a good reference in object-oriented programming and use whatever language (that supports OOP) you are most comfortable with to apply those techniques.

Comment: ""I invented the term object-oriented, and I can tell you that C++ wasn't what I had in mind" -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKg1hTOQXoY&t=634s

Answer (score 23):

If you want a pure OO language, try [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk). Everything is an object in Smalltalk. This is not the case for Java, where primitive types (int, float) aren't objects by themselves.

If it need't be a 'pure' OO language, Java is a good choice because it's more mainstream.

Comment: Yap, Smalltalk is as strict OO as things can get. As far as I remember, there are no operators and no commands except `self` (equivalent to `this` in other languages) and I think something that points to the "static" class members. Everything else is an object, and really everything else. This goes as far as that code blocks are objects, to which you apply `If` and `ElseIf` methods/messages. You have to rethink when doing arithmetics too because there are no operator precedence rules, as `+` and `*` are methods applied to a numeric object and are thus evaluated in the order of occurence.

Comment: @michas Smalltalk will also teach you the MVC pattern, and won't introduce you to the craziness of C++/PHP class systems. You can try ruby, and it will help you learn, (especially the metaprogramming parts), but if you want to know how to do OO-design, the smalltalk libraries are about as good as you'll get.

Comment: I think the "pure" OOP judgments are generally nonsense, produced from narrow thinking. Nothing called OPP (object pure programming) has ever been invented, and in Java, you can't use primitives or operators without wrapping them in objects. Go ahead and try. It's object "oriented".

Comment: Ruby is great too ;)

Answer (score 9):

For a pure Object orientated language, look at [Smalltalk](http://www.squeak.org). I am reading this up at the moment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

The **problem isn't really the language, but the way you use it**.

**We don't use OO features because they are fancy, but because we gain time** (including the long run of course) with them.

May I suggest **having your code reviewed by a fellow programmer**? And you discuss it? And you can review his? I think that feedback would help you much more than reading, or writing code alone, where you don't have to confront or discuss stuff on concrete code.

Answer (score 7):

Try Java or C# on Mono.

**Rationale:**

1. I respect Smalltalk, and one should certainly *know its concepts* to understand OOP better, but learning the language itself is impractical IMHO.
2. While Java and C# might not be "absolutely pure" OOP-wise (e.g. they have incorporated some of the functional programming approaches), they are inherently OOP-based, they are mainstream (thus have much larger communities) and they are easier to learn than Smalltalk IMHO.

Comment: Mono is a framework, not a language. I assume you mean C#.

Comment: Java is not a "pure" Object Oriented Language... It has basic types outside the class hierarchy.

Comment: @fortran: Should we advice Michas to learn Smalltalk-80 and only then something _useful_?

Comment: Technically you can write procedural code with C#/Java (Not sure about Smalltalk) by using static classes/methods.

Comment: @fortran: C# also has primitive types outside the class hierarchy.

Comment: @fortran: Neither is C# a 'pure' Object oriented language..

Comment: @fortran: Oh, we already did actually... =)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, tommieb75 - No, all C# types (including int, bool, etc.) derive from System.Object.

Comment: @Yacoder it would be also useful if we advise him to eat five pieces of fruit a day, but that's not what he was asking either.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, tommieb75 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Common_Type_system_.28CTS.29

Comment: Seconded.  If you want a scripting language, learn Ruby, but if you want to learn a practical language for the purpose of learning OOP, Java or C# are it.  Smalltalk isn't really widely used anywhere outside of academia, nor is Eiffel; having a broad base of support and question and answer sites, Java/C# seem the clear winner.

Comment: I used C# for a while. It looks for me about as OO as C++ with QT 4. It does not force to use any particular paradigm. I do not think C# on Linux is mainstream too.

Comment: @Michas: C# language is not tied to any specific platform and it actually kinda forces you to use OOP... At least it did teach me to use OOP =)

Comment: @Dean J Smalltalk is used mostly in business - not in academia. That's because Smalltalk for a long time was only affordable for big business, costing many thousands of dollars. Have a look at Cincom Systems or the IBM VisualAge tools, which Eclipse was derived from.

Learning Smalltalk was the most eye-opening experience.

Comment: @Richard Durr; hunh.  The only two places I've seen/heard of Smalltalk were academia and DoD, although I'd say the academic projects using it had a high probability of being DARPA funded anyways.

Comment: @Dean J Take a look at http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/blog/blogView?showComments=true&entry=3419278263 for a bit of history. ^^

Answer (score 7):

A lot of people are suggesting Smalltalk, so I'm going to be different and suggest [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language)). ;)

A good language to learn OO principles on, also has neat stuff like DBC (Design By Contract).

Comment: Eiffel isn't a programming language.

Comment: @RogerF.Gay: Ok, you could explain what it is?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not the language. No matter what language you use, you could still code everything in one class, or using class level methods, and end up writing structured code. While a pure OO language will make it harder, I've graded plenty of students who try to shoehorn structured programming into Java and C#.

My suggestion would be to look through some good examples of OO programming, and to look at how OO lends itself to certain design patterns that really show off the power of OO to do the same things structured programming does but with less code that is much more readable to other programmers.

Comment: Good suggestions, but I'd suggest *first* talking to colleagues or friends: it's usually more fun and a better use of (probably limited) time.

Comment: Doh. Of course, I forgot about the talking to coworkers bit. That is almost always my first step when doing something new, and it was one of those so obvious things that I forgot it.

Answer (score 5):

Read the article  **[Design Principles Behind Smalltalk](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/smalltalk.html)** from Daniel H. H. Ingalls, who implemented Smalltalk. It dictates the true essence of OOP.

Comment: https://pharo.org Pharo is a pure object-oriented programming language and a powerful environment, focused on simplicity and immediate feedback (think IDE and OS rolled into one). Pharo is a standalone language. It is not supposed to be an implementation of Smalltalk-80 nor ANSI Smalltalk. Pharo relies on a virtual machine that is written almost entirely in Smalltalk itself. It is based on general concepts of Smalltalk but does not want to be limited by them.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest python. It passes the "everything is an object => pure OO language" criteria mentioned by a few others for choosing Smalltalk. Functions and even the python null value (`None`) are all objects.

It is *more* OO than Java (java has `int` and `Integer`). And more importantly, it is vastly more popular than Smalltalk, so you're more likely to be able to get help with it.

Python also does polymorphism without inheritance ("duck-typing") and functional programming, both of which are becoming more common in "mainstream" languages.

Answer (score 3):

Learn the paradigm and then which language you choose matters less.

[Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design: A Brain Friendly Guide to OOA&D](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Object-Oriented-Analysis-Design/dp/0596008678/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264611902&sr=1-5)
[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51eQgNjOOWL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU02_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51eQgNjOOWL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU02_.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better if you just keep doing what you're doing and gradually try to work OO into your coding style in multiparadigm languages.  OO is a great way of modeling some things, but **it's not the be all and end all of programming.**  OO is great where you need flexibility.  Procedural is a perfectly good paradigm for parts of your code where you want a simple solution to a simple problem and don't need a lot of abstraction.

Learning a "pure" OO language will give you a feel for *how* to use OO features, but as you won't be forced to choose what paradigm to use for any given piece of code, it won't give you a good feel *when* to use them.  I think a much better way to learn practical OO, as opposed to OO as a religion, is to learn a multiparadigm language like D, Python or Ruby (or stick with C++ and PHP, though the OO features of these languages are very "bolted on"), read up on design patterns to understand the "why" of OO, and gradually try to integrate more OO design into your programs, with the ability to compare the results to what you would have written procedurally in the same language.  The OO version will often be better, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Common Lisp Object System (CLOS).  It is not "pure" OOP like Smalltalk but the type hierarchy in lisp is at least complete (which is more than can be said for Java), and most other languages, even OO languages, don't have generic methods, multidispatch, method combinations, esp :before, :after and :around. run-time class objects, or reinitialize-instance, all of which CLOS provides.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take an Agile like approach and just write the code the way you feel must natural to you. Then try to re-factor it to OO paradigm. I very much recommend Marin Fowler's classic on the subject (refactoring) and then a good delve into Gang-of-four's Design Patterns (very well-known, unmistakable), then perhaps Joshua Kerievsky's "Refactoring to Patterns" and again Fowler's PoEAA , can get you very far indeed in understanding and *thinking* in OO.

This is in shear contrast with the Up-Front-Deisng like approach of trying to do OO after reading stuff about OO concepts. No need to mention a good theoretical background is well paid when trying the Agile-like approach but the spirit is to refactor yourself into OO instead of pivoting from anything you are now doing to OO.

Answer (score 1):

Object-oriented programming has very little to do with what language you use and a lot to do with your approach to programming. Object-oriented programming depends on how you plan things and how you structure your code. You could use a language like Java, which forces you to use some object-oriented features, but if just sat down and put all your code in the `main()` method you have not done any object oriented programming.

My suggestion is not to learn a different language, but to study the paradigm of object-oriented programming itself and the various ways a program is planned and implemented using object-oriented analysis and design. Learn about abstraction, encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism to start. Get a good feel for UML. Then study design patterns that are used in object-oriented programming.

Make sure you're doing all these things before you code. The biggest shock you may face is how much time you have to think before you code anything. Spending the time to plan your program in an object-oriented way is very difficult for people accustomed to just sitting down and coding in a process-oriented way. If you take the time to plan what you're going to do in advance (of course don't go too crazy since programming is about small iterations), you'll find you can create much better code the first time, for increasingly complex tasks.

Answer (score -2):

I see a lot of suggestions here to learn languages that are frankly not marketable.  As a young person you may not care and have this zest for learning (I know b/c I've been there), but down the road when it comes time to put food on the table you will regret screwing around with these languages.  Ada is honestly my favorite language and I'd love to program in it for a career, but she don't pay the bills so I had to break it off with her.  :(

Comment: Your opinion is very practical, but I think you might have missed the point of learning new languages that support a given paradigm.  If you learn several of these languages and appreciate their intent, you'll be a better more well rounded developer.  If you do this, you'll be able to put more food on the table since you're better at what you do.