# How is Java a 'pure OOP language'?

Tags: java, oop

What makes java a '**pure'** OOP language?

What is a pure OOP language?
What is a not-pure OOP language?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148559/looking-for-a-pure-object-oriented-language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Java is not because it supports Primitive datatype[^] such as int, byte, long... etc, to be used, which are not objects.

There are seven features to be satisfied for a programming language to be pure Object Oriented. They are:

1. Encapsulation/Data Hiding
2. Inheritance
3. Polymorphism
4. Abstraction
5. All predefined types are objects
6. All operations are performed by sending messages to objects
7. All user defined types are objects.

Comment: Those severe things are not qualities, but features. I do not know about your origin of that points. And according to point 6 you should not be able to use any static elements in your application.

Comment: @Vash yes you are right those are not qualities but features of pure OOP language

Comment: In Scala you can do `object.field = value`. This is an operation performed without sending messages (or calling methods) on the language level although on byte-code level is compiled to method call. Does this make scala *not* pure OO language?

Answer (score 2):

Java is not a pure OOP language because it supports primitives like:

```
int i = 5;
boolean b = false;
```

which is in contrast with languages like Smalltalk (for example), where there are no primitive types and `int`, `boolean`, etc. are all Objects.

Comment: That's acctually an argument AGAINST OPs thesis ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Nope because there are other thing which are not Objects in Java like primitive types. [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) is a pure OOP language.

Answer (score 1):

Java is not a pure OOP language since it has primitive data types.

Pure OOP languages only have objects.